# What is the intuition behind TD($\lambda$)?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, comparison, monte-carlo-methods, temporal-difference-methods, td-lambda

I'd like to better understand temporal-difference learning. In particular, I'm wondering if it is prudent to think about TD($\lambda$) as a type of "truncated" Monte Carlo learning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TD($\lambda$) can be thought of as a combination of TD and MC learning, so as to avoid to choose one method or the other and to take advantage of both approaches.

More precisely, TD($\lambda$) is temporal-difference learning with a $\lambda$-return, which is defined as an average of all $n$-step returns, for all $n$, where an $n$-step return is the *target* used to update the estimate of the value function that contains $n$ future rewards (plus an estimate of the value function of the state $n$ steps in the future). For example, TD(0) (e.g. Q-learning is usually presented as a TD(0) method) uses a $1$-step return, that is, it uses one future reward (plus an estimate of the value of the next state) to compute the target. The letter $\lambda$ actually refers to a parameter used in this context to weigh the combination of TD and MC methods. There are actually two different perspectives of TD($\lambda$), the *forward view* and the *backward view* (eligibility traces).

The blog post [Reinforcement Learning: Eligibility Traces and TD(lambda)](https://amreis.github.io/ml/reinf-learn/2017/11/02/reinforcement-learning-eligibility-traces.html) gives a quite intuitive overview of TD($\lambda$), and, for more details, read [the related chapter of the book *Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction*](http://incompleteideas.net/book/RLbook2020.pdf#page=309).

Answer (score 2):

I am a novice in Reinforcement Learning and I have been struggling for several monthes about the TD()'s logic. Initially it seemed to me that it was a successfull purely heuristic formula without any theoretical foundation. But nowadays,  I understand it simply as a mean's calculation, using the recurrent formula that states that when you a have a mean and a new value arrives, it modifies the mean by an amount equal to its difference with it (the mean) divided by the new values number.

To summarize, the exposed mean calculation is an instance of a general formula of recurrent mean calculation that uses as increasing factor for the difference between the new value and the actual mean multiplied by any number between 0 and 1. By the way, this number - usually called  *step size parameter* - can be dynamic, and in the first paragraph (usual mean calculation) its amount is the inverse of the number of values considered in the mean's calculation.

Intuitively, we can understand that it is an accurate estimation procedure independently the initial (guessed or not) value. With a high number of estimates (new values arriving), the initial values fades its importance, and that it can be extended to treat many (lambda) new values simultaneously.

Until now I have not found this explanation nowhere, even if it is very simple, and I am not so sure that it is sound. I will appreciate if someone let me know if this intuition is correct and if it has already been exposed somewhere.